# MVC4 Areas, HomeControllers and Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

http://blog.falafel.com/duplicate-controller-names-aspnet-mvc-areas/

Followed this advice and am now running.  However, when hitting /area/home/index the correct controller action fires but it is using the Index.cshtml from the root site rather than the Index.cshtml from the Area folder!  Any ideas how to "fix" this?

Or is there a better way to handle routing to accomplish the same thing?

Goal:
http://example.net/  -> HomeController / Index (root)
http://example.net/area1  -> area1.HomeController.Index / area1's Index.cshtml
http://example.net/area1/NotIndex  -> area1.HomeController.NotIndex / area1's NotIndex.cshtml
http://example.net/area2  -> area2.HomeController.Index / area2's Index.cshtml
etc...

I tried attribute routing for a different area.

```
[RouteArea("ProductReuse")]
[Route("ProductReuse")]
public partial class ProductReuseController : BaseProductReuseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (SessionUserLogin == null) return LoginActionResult(SessionAppName);

        var serviceResponse = _productReuseService.IndexQuery(SessionUserId);
        var response = _mapper.Map<IndexViewModel>(serviceResponse);

        return View(response);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is close but you still have to have an URL that looks like:
http://example.net/ProductReuse/Index

If you try to hit http://example.net/ProductReuse it bombs out.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that you can add an empty string route name to the routing attribute.

```
[RouteArea("ProductReuse")]
[Route("ProductReuse")]
public partial class ProductReuseController : BaseProductReuseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Index")]
    [Route("")]  // Use an empty name to set the default page...
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (SessionUserLogin == null) return LoginActionResult(SessionAppName);

        var serviceResponse = _productReuseService.IndexQuery(SessionUserId);
        var response = _mapper.Map<IndexViewModel>(serviceResponse);

        return View(response);
    }
    ...
}
```